# How to manually add a Google authenticated user to Microsoft Identity via a web API call (.NET Core)

Tags: api, google-oauth, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, claims-based-identity

Background:

I am developing an application with a .NET Core API as backend and a React SPA as frontend.
My plan is to be able to write any other frontend application (say for mobile) and both be able to use the same backend API.
I have not started with any frontend work yet but only have the starting blocks of my API.
For security I thought that I wanted to try to add Google Authentication as most people I know uses Gmail but also to make it "more appealing" to try the application once is up and running. Also just for learning purposes and for fun .

I have been able to setup Google Authentication and secure my API routes with the [Authorize] attribute. Once I did that when I try to call the API route I get prompted to login to Google and only then I can get the response from my API Route. So far so good!

Now I want to be able to sign up users and handle their roles through my API (as I want the API to be the only one handling all calls). I do not want to use Identity.UI because that part will be handled by any frontend application that I build for using with my API. That is the goal at least...

Note: Also the reason I went with .NET Identity and Google Authentication is because I did not want to use JWT if popssible (maybe I'm wrong in this)

Question:

- How do I manually add a new user from Google Authentication into .NET Identity via an API call? Is it even possible to do it? I can't find any information on the internet regarding this, only tutorials that use Identity.UI (Microsoft)
- What information do I need to store from the Claims into the .NET Identity database? I can't even find an identifier inside the Claims object
- How will the application know that the user is User A from google and not User B from google or another service? Do I just check the IsAuthenticated and the name? I suspect that I would need to do a call to Google and ask for the Scope that contains the User information but I would like to have a confirmation of this in that case and also what properties to compare

What I've tried:

I have not been able to try so much as I am not sure where to begin. The only thing I have done is to inspect the Claims object to see what information may be pertinent to store and some identifiers but have not been able to find anything that pops out as obvious. Edit: I found a nameidentifier value inside the claims

I have also done a lot of googling but maybe my google kung fu is not as strong as I think it is...

The code and the claims:

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<IncumbenciaAPIContext>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientId"] ?? "";
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Google:Secret"] ?? "";
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
});
```

Controller.cs:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet(Name = "GetAll[controller]s")]
    public List<SubscriberSummaryDto> GetAll()
    {
        //Dummy code just to analize the claims I get when I call the API
        var user = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        return _subscriberService.GetAllSubscribers();
    }
```

Claims:
[image: User claim values]

Thanks in advance for any input regarding this!
Happy coding !

Comment: Have you consider using two authentication schema for your web api? Identity and google Oauth at same time, this means you could get a JWT toke from the google and directly use that token to the web api.

Comment: @BrandoZhang thanks for the reply! Maybe I am not understanding JWT and identity, but the way I setup the api is already to use .NET identity and I just added Google as an authentication provider. Do I need to use JWT? (I wanted to avoid it if possible) I thought that it was possible just to use Oauth2 but maybe like I said I am not understanding the basics. Could you point me to an example or a blog? 
Thanks!

Comment: The google auth is also using the JWT token, you could follow this article to use it inside web api. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @BrandoZhang thanks again for the reply! I already followed the steps on that article to set up google as an authentication provider. This article though sign up users with Identity UI, what I am trying to achieve is to not use the frontend provided by .NET identity. I just want to call my API and sign up the user that way. I get the users claim on my API call after they authenticated through Google but then I don't know what information to store, like I said before I don't even find an identifier for my authenticated user. I will update my post so maybe it is easier to follow what I mean 

Comment: Hi, no you SHOULD need 2 controllers: [1 web controller with cookie auth and xsrf protection, for any type of SPA web application](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Server/Controllers/Web/V3/AccountController.cs) and [1 api controller with bearer auth for mobile applications](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Server/Controllers/Api/V1/AccountController.cs). I've written a whole rant about this [here](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/asp-net-core-angular-xsrf-62c3833fd1fe)

Comment: @BrandoZhang I found an identifier now that I was updating my post with some code  so maybe not all hope is lost for me yet hehe. This brings some follow-up questions: Is that a unique identifier for the user in Google? (So I can use it to store the user in my identity database) and I suppose the roles are something that I still have to handle within Identity and not with Google Oauth right? I ask because I also saw that the claims from Google have a RoleClaimType but it feels more logical that my backend will handle those... am I on the right track at least? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Pieterjan thanks for the input! Maybe I am misuderstanding but isn't using Oauth2 something different than using Cookie Authentication? I am sorry if I'm mistaken on the basics but I just want to understand them better  I will check out the xsrf post as well!

Comment: Integrating Google OpenIDConnect directly in your frontend application would be really burdensome, and not really extendible. It should be implemented in your backend. I've built an [example application here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data/Repositories/AccountRepository.cs#L204-L344). Configuration is [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Startup.cs#L70-L77). If this is too much, I've also created a [`dotnet` template](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates) where you can select all of these opts

Comment: Tbh I wouldn't even know where you'd want to store your google clientid and ClientSecret if you'd use google oauth directly in your angular app. Your ClientSecret should remain, well, secret. And anything in your frontend is not that. You NEED a backend

Comment: Thanks again for the reply @Pieterjan! What you say is true, maybe I need to rethink how I am structuring the different layers of my application. I still want my API to be the one and only accesspoint to my app. Maybe its possible for my backend to handle all negotiations with Google? I think I see now why Brando was also telling me that I would still need JWT between my frontend and my api.
Thanks again for the input! 